# unseralize + php gives convert original value

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

Here is my string I want unserialize this string.

```
$string3 = 'a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"value";d:4.0999999999999996;s:7:"players";a:2:{i:6;i:6;i:7;i:7;}}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"value";d:10.899999999999999;s:7:"players";a:1:{i:7;i:7;}}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"value";d:1.7763568394002505E-15;s:7:"players";N;}}';
```

and it gives below result

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [value] => 4.1 // this value converted to 4.1 original was see in the string it was 4.0999999999999996
        [players] => Array
            (
                [6] => 6
                [7] => 7
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [value] => 10.9 // this value converted to 10.9 original was see in the string it was 10.899999999999999
        [players] => Array
            (
                [7] => 7
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [value] => 1.7763568394003E-15
        [players] => 
    )

)
```

it converts array value to 4.1 and 10.9 etc. I want original value not converted.

Comment: Ok...what is the question ?

Comment: see the comment on array

Comment: unserialize http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I know this function and how to use I am just asking why it converts result... strange why every one down voting it.

Comment: I guess it is not possible to store `4.1` value and to use it. We see it as `4.1` but PHP can only save `4.0999999999999996`, and on this value it operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard for computers to handle floats with precision. Without going into much details PHP simply has set a value for the max amount of floating point values. This is set in the `precision` config property. It is probably set to 14, so every float that has 14 or more floating numbers will be rounded.

So what you need to do is increase the `precision` value in your php.ini. Or change it with `ini_set('precision', 20)`.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Note that the precision setting has no effect on serialize, which often *has* to store a lot of digits in order to provide enough detail to get back the original binary value. Adjusting the precision in this case is just a hack to make the value display similarly to the way serialize stored it. But the original value probably *was* 4.1. So really, unserialize was functioning fine.